# Choose Atom as my script editor for Unity3D, problem with autocomplete

Tags: unity, editors

I am trying to configure Atom, so that when I edit my C# scripts from my project, I am aided by the Unity autocomplete. So far, I am able to open the project and every time I type an error in Atom, Unity shows it in its logs. But you get my point, for example, when I am using Visual Studio, I have had this autocomplete functionality from the beginning without having me to do anything in particular.

I went to External Tools and choose the **atom.exe** from the following the **AppData folder** path. I am required some **External Script Editor Args** and I am not sure what to type there. After doing all of this, I pressed **Open C# Project** from the **Assets drop-down menu** as I have read that this syncs the project. Atom opened, I had the project in the tree-view and when I start editing, I did not get the autocomplete functionality.

Does anyone else use Atom or at least Sublime as text editor? Did you stumble over this issue too?